# Can terraform plan show me a json diff for a changed resource?

Tags: terraform

When I run `terraform plan` it shows a changed resource, which happens to be JSON data in an `aws_s3_bucket_object`. But the JSON is long and it's difficult to see what changed. How can I display this as a diff?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

https://github.com/coinbase/terraform-landscape can help with this.

1. `gem install terraform_landscape` (may need sudo on macOS)
2. `terraform plan | landscape`

This shows JSON changes as a diff. Here's an example from the github site:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a bash script to format terraforms ugly policy output:

```
#!/bin/bash

input=$( xclip -o )

old=$( echo "$input" | awk -F' => ' '{ print $1 }'  | sed 's/\\n/\n\r/g' | sed 's/\\"/"/g' | sed 's/"{/{/' | sed 's/}"/}/' )
new=$( echo "$input" | awk -F' => ' '{ print $2 }'  | sed 's/\\n/\n\r/g' | sed 's/\\"/"/g' | sed 's/"{/{/' | sed 's/}"/}/' )

echo "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "old:"
echo "$old" | jq '.'
echo "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "new:"
echo "$new" | jq '.'
echo "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "diff:"
diff -u --color <( echo "$old" | jq '.' ) <( echo "$new" | jq '.' )
echo "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
```

It shows three blocks of output, the old, then the new and then the diff. It makes use of `xclip`, `jq` and `diff`. Usage is (on Linux) to highlight the terrafrom output and then invoke the script (I call it `tf-diff` and it lives in `~/bin`).